# How to embed UITabBar inside another UITabBar in storyboard xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am creating an ios app that has a tab bar with 2 items as the first screen.Each screen further needs to have a tab bar with 4 items. In story board (xcode), I am able to create the initial screen using the "tab bar controller". This controller creates "first" and "second" view controllers. But, I am unable to link up another "tab bar controller" to the first/second view controllers. How should I accomplish this in storyboard? Or will I have to do it programmatically? If so how? Please advice.

Comment: Not sure if you can have two tab controllers. But you can add/remove controllers to TabBarController and show two/four buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating the sub controllers that you want.
In this method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Set up a switch, to figure out which tab bar controller was selected using the tabBarController object.

In the code for tabControllerA, and in that same method in which you set up your tabbarcontroller check, add in a line like this

```
[window addSubview:someOtherTabBarController.view];
```

To remove a sub tab bar controller, just have that same function call

```
[someTabBarController.view removeFromSuperView];
```